# Why am I getting /n/n in my excel output on python?

Tags: python, excel

In my excel file, the only thing I see in the mileage columns is the actual value, so for example the first line I see “35 kmpl”. Why is it putting /n/n before every value when I get python to print my file?

I was expecting just the kmpl values in that column but instead I’m getting /n/n infront of them on python.

[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YSNI9.png)

here is my code pasted, I didn't get an error message so I can't put that:

```
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
    bikes = pd.read_csv('/content/bikes sorted final.csv')
    print(bikes)
```

which returns:

```
                        model_name          model_year kms_driven        owner  
    0        Bajaj Avenger Cruise 220 2017        2017   17000 Km  first owner   
    1     Royal Enfield Classic 350cc 2016        2016   50000 Km  first owner   
    2                  Hyosung GT250R 2012        2012   14795 Km  first owner   
    3                  KTM Duke 200cc 2012        2012   24561 Km  third owner   
    4              Bajaj Pulsar 180cc 2016        2016   19718 Km  first owner
```

...

```
           location     mileage         power   price  
    0     hyderabad  \n\n 35 kmpl     19 bhp   63500  
    1     hyderabad  \n\n 35 kmpl  19.80 bhp  115000  
    2     hyderabad  \n\n 30 kmpl     28 bhp  300000  
    3     bangalore  \n\n 35 kmpl     25 bhp   63400  
    4     bangalore  \n\n 65 kmpl     17 bhp   55000
```

Comment: Please add the code you are using.

Comment: _Why is it putting /n/n before every value when I get python to print my file_ We cannot possibly answer that without seeing your code...

Comment: sorry I am new to this..I added the picture link now

Comment: If you do [tour] you'll read that you should share textual code and error messages rather than pictures which cannot be searched, or copy/pasted.

Comment: Edit the question to include the output you get from `print(bikes)`.

Comment: And while you're at it, also include the contents of that csv file.

Comment: It looks like there are actual `\n` characters in the `location` column in the csv file.